# how can I see battery level of headphones connected via bluetooth to iPhone iOS 12.5.5

Tags: iphone, ipad, bluetooth

how can I see the battery level of headphones connected via Bluetooth to iPhone iOS 12.5.5 or an iPad also on ios 12.

Comment: Are the headphones designed to send that information?

Comment: yes I see it on ios 13.

Comment: I meant ios 15.